# Reapply selection after ajax refresh of panel

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a panelGroup which is ajax refreshed whenever the text in a textbox within the panelGroup changes due to a change event on the textbox. Due to this if I change the text and directly click on a radio button (in the same panelGroup) the radio button loses its value. However if I click elsewhere and then click on the radio button it retains its value.
I would like the radio button to retain its value. The code for the panel, textbox and radio are :

```
<h:panelGroup id="addSection">
    <h:inputText id="osRef" value="#{detailsController.osRef}" 
        disabled="#{!empty detailsController.id}" maxlength="14"
        validatorMessage="ERROR" binding="#{detailsController.refInput}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="#{regexp.GRID_REF}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="addSection"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <h:selectOneRadio id="isLfaRadio" value="#{detailsController.isLfa}" 
        disabled="#{!empty detailsController.id}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
        <a4j:ajax event="click" render="addSection"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to re-render the radio button on change of input text? Perhaps you're simply re-rendering "too much" and you actually need to re-render only more specific parts? That binding attribute is fishy, by the way.

Comment: Due to the change event on the inputText as soon as I click the radio, it loses it's value. I just want the radio to retain the selected value whether by re-rendering or by some other approach.

Comment: I know. However, I didn't ask that.

Comment: Is there a way I could stop re-rendering the radio button when the panelGroup is re-rendered?

Comment: Just re-render only more specific parts which really need to be re-rendered. Exactly as I asked/hinted in my 1st comment.

Comment: Resolved the issue by rendering only the specific components instead of the whole panel. Thanks BalusC.